# Regex Proxy Server

Tags: php, regex, apache, proxy, proxy-server

I control access via a proxy server and run some regex on every request. For prototype I have used curl, regex and php. Obviously this will not put up with any serious load. Can anyone suggest and proxy servers that would be suitable?

Answer (score 0):

Why do need to 'run' some regexp? For rewriting the request url? In that case, Apache can do it, it has a proxy module and a (regexp based) rewriting engine. I used it, once, so i'm sure those functions can be combined.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html

But Squid is designed to be a proxy server (not a web server) and wil most probably be able to do some URL rewriting as well.